# I can't figure out how to do this DISTINCT

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Good morning

I tried and tried to understand why this Query gives the usual error on Group By. I would like to find the duplicate lines and delete them. I found this query on Microsoft's MSDN but despite this it keeps giving me this error on Group By.
The main table has 3 fields "Id, Item, Description", the table name is "tlbDescription", this query should in theory create a table named "duplicate_table"  insert the duplicate values inside the "duplicate_table", then delete the values from table "tlbDescription" and finally delete the table "duplicate_table".
If someone can kindly give me a hand
Thank you
Fabrizio
This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO duplicate_table
FROM [tlbDescrizione]
GROUP BY [Articolo]
HAVING COUNT([Articolo]) > 1

DELETE [tlbDescrizione]
WHERE [Articolo]  IN (SELECT [Articolo] FROM duplicate_table)

INSERT [tlbDescrizione] 
SELECT * FROM duplicate_table

DROP TABLE duplicate_table
```

Comment: Have you tried semicolons at the end of each query?  Your question mentions "query" in the singular but your code has four statements.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Your first query doesn't make sense. The only way you could legally group by `Articolo` and select all columns is if `Articolo` is the primary key, but it is the primary key, then it both the `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query doesn't make sense:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO duplicate_table
FROM [tlbDescrizione]
GROUP BY [Articolo]
HAVING COUNT([Articolo]) > 1;
```

It is selecting all columns but is an aggregation query because of the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, the `SELECT` columns are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` columns and you get an error.

If you want all the columns then you can use window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO duplicate_table
FROM (SELECT d.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Articolo) as cnt
      FROM tlbDescrizione d
     ) d
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Or, if you want only the ids:

```
SELECT Articolo
INTO duplicate_table
FROM tlbDescrizione
GROUP BY [Articolo]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```